# LDAP search method - Multithreading and Improvement in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, ldap

Does ldap support multithreading in java? 
Because in my application the search method is called very often (150x) in the case that the user want to see all data. Therefore the user have to wait at least 10 seconds.
If it's not supported, do you have any ideas to improve the search?

Answer (score 0):

If by Java you mean the JNDI API, then the API is inherently synchronous.
You can achieve asynchronous calls by using multiple threads as explained in the JDNI tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/misc/sync.html

Alternately, you could use a Java based LDAP SDK like OpenDJ's (https://forgerock.org/opendj/) which is by default asynchronous and can be used to support very high throughput. We use it to run performance tests and can sustain rates in the range of 50 000 to 100 000 search requests per second.